# Source control of a new target in Xcode 4 project

Tags: xcode, svn, target

I have a project under source control (remote SVN).
Originally the project had just one target. Whenever I added a new file to the project, it was added to SVN automatically. I was happy with that.

However, when I created a new target, its files were **not** put under source control. What did I miss? Is there a way to correct this from *inside* Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly enough, I've found the answer myself :) You just have to commit once, and new files will be added.